# WP8 Access Build Settings programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, msbuild

I want to use conditional compiling in Windows Phone 8. For this I have to add the values in my Properties/Build Tab. I have approximately 150 values that I want to define and I don't think this approach is feasible to me. I did a workaround and found out that we can add these values in .csproj file.

Considering an example where I have two conditional compiling values, refer the below pic
[image]

I can use these SUPPORTS_PRINTING value in my code,

```
 #if  SUPPORTS_PRINTING 
-- perform my logic--
 #endif
```

But adding these values(I mean to say it's okay for some 10 values, but how about 150 values? ) in my Build tab is a long process. I would like to declare all of these values in a .xml file and I want to link them to DefineConstants (like in the image).

Thanks.

Comment: Why not to create static class (utility class) if you want to access this options from the code?

Comment: Yes, and no. You could theoretically access those settings from text template files, but since they are in the project definition file, you should not really do that. Can you please post more details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to access these DefineConstant values from my code. I have a .xml file which has the constant values that I have defined in the example, I want to read the values from .xml file and add them to these DefineConstant. Is it doable?

Comment: You can't define constants at runtime.

Comment: Seems to me that the time spent creating and updating the separate XML file  is equivalent to the time you'd spend editing the .csproj file (which is also an XML file).  For maintenance sake, it seems better to keep the constants in the build file (which is where they normally live).